# Скопировать значения из таблицы, присоединенной joinом

Tags: sql, база-данных, plsql, plsql-developer

Есть таблица, в которую добавлен пустой столбец.
Есть другая таблица, которая соединяется по `id` с первоначальной. 
Во второй таблице есть столбец **et.verification_period** - его значения необходимо скопировать в столбец **et_attestation_period** первой таблицы. Однако девелопер ругается, что подзапрос возвращает более одной строки:

```
update equipment
set et_attestation_period = (select et.verification_period from metrology.equipment_type et
                              join metrology.equipment e on et.id = e.equipment_type_id)
```

Прошу помочь с написанием верного селекта для подобной операции.

Comment: Добрый день. Для начала вам надо определиться что вы хотите получить. Скорее всего, `et.id` в основной таблице уникален, а во второй таблице к этому ключу идёт связка "один ко многим". Т.е. во второй таблице может быть несколько записей, относящихся к `et.id`. Определитесь по какой логике вы хотите перенести эти несколько записей? Если один одинаковые - добавьте `TOP 1` в подзапрос.

Comment: @Deft, в таблице equipment e есть столбец с уникальными значениями e.id. Ему соответствует столбец e.equipment_type_id - который содержит в себе значения из таблицы equipment_type et. Джойнятся эти таблицы по e.equipment_type_id = et.id. Каждому значению et.id соответствует значение et.verification_period. Это значение мне необходимо присвоить каждой записи в таблице equipment(столбец et_attestation period). Вот вся логика.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update equipment
set et_attestation_period = (select verification_period 
                             from equipment_type
                             where equipment_type.id = equipment.equipment_type_id
                            )
```

Comment: Equipment - таблица на 200к записей, но запрос хотя бы выполняется.) Спасибо!

Comment: *Equipment - таблица на 200к записей* а какая разница - сколько? впрочем, индекс `equipment(equipment_type_id)` был бы полезен. А индекс `equipment_type(id)`, вероятно, и так имеется.

Comment: и лучше бы все таки использовать [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606)